# Angular try from local json file find by id

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, find

I have local json file (Kitchen types), i create KitchenTypesService there are 2 inside function GET AND FIND(ID), GET function its work, but not working find function, have error "ERROR TypeError: Unable to lift unknown Observable type", i try with find function get kitchen with id. Tell me what's the problem

Service

```
export class KitchenTypesService {
  private _jsonURL = 'assets/data/kitchenTypes.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.get().subscribe((data) => data);
  }

  public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this._jsonURL);
  }

  public find(id: number) {
    this.get().subscribe(find((data: any) => data.id == id));
  }
}
```

Component

```
export class KitchenDimensionComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'Virtuvės matmenys';
  step: number = 2;
  selectedKitchenId: number;
  kitchen: any;
  constructor(
    private persistenceService: PersistenceService,
    private httpKitchenTypes: KitchenTypesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initialSelectedKitchenId();
    console.log(this.httpKitchenTypes.find(1));
  }

  initialSelectedKitchenId(): void {
    this.selectedKitchenId = this.persistenceService.get('selectedKitchenId');
  }
}
```

Local KitcehTypes.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Standartine",
    "src": "/assets/images/kitchen-types/one-well.png",
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "L forma",
    "src": "/assets/images/kitchen-types/L-shaped.png",
  },

  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "U forma",
    "src": "/assets/images/kitchen-types/U-shaped.png",
  },

  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "G forma",
    "src": "/assets/images/kitchen-types/G-shaped.png",
  }
]
```

Error Message

[[image: Error Message1]

Comment: I would imagine it is because your JSON doesn't have a selectedKitchenId property on it. Furthermore if your get is expecting a number why are you passing a string and not the variable itself?

Comment: Problme not selectedKitchenId, i have find function in find function i pass number example find(1) but can't find it anyway.

Comment: You should return an observable and subscribe it within the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few ways to tackle this. You're right, HttpClient does cause the error you mentioned, but there is a way around this. May be this can help you.

Directly importing the JSON file using **resolveJsonModule**
To work with this, you'll need to add the following in your **tsconfig.json** file

`"resolveJsonModule": true` 
 Then you can simply import your data by adding this in your service:

`import * as data from './kitchenTypes.json'`

**Note that your will need to update the file path accordingly**

Once this is done, you can now access the JSON file data. You can view, and search the contents of the JSON file as per your need.

`data: any = (data as any).default;`